# Query is taking too much time to execute despite of applying indexing in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, indexing

I have a query below which I want to optimise as best as I can. For the same I have applied indexing on column : `constructordate`. and `STATUS` also.

But into my guess the indexing is not working for INNER queries

```
SELECT (SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(R4GSTATENAME)  FROM R4G_BU.JIOCENTERBOUNDARY WHERE SAP_ID=TM.JC_SAP_ID AND ROWNUM=1) as STATENAME,
JC_SAP_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT FSAID) AS ACTUAL_VALUE ,'FSA CWIP' AS CAT, 'MONTHLY' as DURATION,constructordate   
FROM FTTX_TASKMASTER TM
WHERE constructordate >= to_date('01-01-24','DD-MM-YY') and  constructordate < to_date('31-01-24','DD-MM-YY')+1
AND fsaid NOT IN (
SELECT fsaid
FROM FTTX_TASKMASTER
WHERE constructordate <= TO_DATE('01-12-23','DD-MM-YY')) AND
STATUS IN('COMPLETED','ACCEPTED','REJECTED') AND JC_SAP_ID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY JC_SAP_ID,constructordate;
```

Please suggest we can modify and change query if required as per needed.

**Note**: The table `FTTX_TASKMASTER` is used at various places

Below is the DDL statement

```html
CREATE TABLE FTTX_TASKMASTER
(
  TASKID NVARCHAR2(25)
, TASKTYPE NVARCHAR2(20)
, FSAID NVARCHAR2(20)
, DSAID NVARCHAR2(20)
, CSAID NVARCHAR2(20)
, MDUID NVARCHAR2(50)
, LAYER NVARCHAR2(20)
, STATUS NVARCHAR2(10)
, FEEDERNO NVARCHAR2(20)
, CONTRACTORNAME NVARCHAR2(50)
, CONTRACTORDATE DATE
, ACCEPTORNAME NVARCHAR2(50)
, ACCEPTORDATE DATE
, CONTRACTORID NVARCHAR2(15)
, CONTRACTORCOMPANY NVARCHAR2(25)
, REV NUMBER(5, 0)
, APPVERSION NVARCHAR2(5)
, CONSTRUCTORNAME NVARCHAR2(50)
, CONSTRUCTORID NVARCHAR2(50)
, CONSTRUCTORDATE DATE
, ROLE NVARCHAR2(50)
, CREATED_USER NVARCHAR2(255)
, CREATED_DATE DATE DEFAULT sysdate
, LAST_EDITED_USER NVARCHAR2(255)
, LAST_EDITED_DATE DATE
, OBJECTID NUMBER(*, 0) NOT NULL
, NE_STATUS NVARCHAR2(3) DEFAULT 'N'
, UPDATEFLAG NUMBER(5, 0)
, REMARKS VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE)
, ASSIGNEDBY NVARCHAR2(100)
, ASSIGNEDTO NVARCHAR2(100)
, ASSIGNED_DATE DATE
, ISBLOCKED NVARCHAR2(20)
, HOTODONE NVARCHAR2(20)
, SOURCE NVARCHAR2(10)
, ROW_REQUIRED NVARCHAR2(10)
, DSANAME NVARCHAR2(50)
, CSANAME NVARCHAR2(50)
, NE_REMARKS VARCHAR2(500 BYTE)
, IS_QA_REMARK VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
, OFFER_CODE VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
, OFFER_STATUS VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
, JC_SAP_ID VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
, JCNAME VARCHAR2(240 BYTE)
, FSANAME VARCHAR2(240 BYTE)
, ROLEUSER VARCHAR2(240 BYTE)
, WORKORDER VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
, PENDINGWITH VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
, MODIFIEDDATE DATE DEFAULT NULL
, INPROGRESS VARCHAR2(5 CHAR) DEFAULT 'FALSE'
, PRIORITY NUMBER
, USER_LAT NVARCHAR2(20)
, USER_LONG NVARCHAR2(20)
, CONTRACTOR_STRATEGY NVARCHAR2(20)
, NE_WO_NAME VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
, NE_WO_OBJECTID VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
, NE_WO_MIGRATION_DATE DATE
, NE_NEW_NAME VARCHAR2(150 BYTE)
, DEVIATION_ACTION VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
, K2_INVOICESTATUS VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
, JIOPOINT_SAPID VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
, JIOPOINT_NAME VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
, OFFER_SOURCE VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
, SOLUTION_TYPE NVARCHAR2(100)
, SOLUTION_ID NVARCHAR2(100)
, LEAD_ID NVARCHAR2(100)
, ENT_TASK_TYPE NVARCHAR2(100)
, LEAD_NAME NVARCHAR2(250)
, DOCUMENT_PATH NVARCHAR2(700)
, REQUEST_ID NVARCHAR2(80)
, RFS_STATUS NVARCHAR2(15)
, SUB_CATEGORY NVARCHAR2(250)
)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 1
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 81920
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)CREATE INDEX CONSTRUCTOR_DATE_INDEX ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (CONSTRUCTORDATE ASC)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 2
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 65536
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)

CREATE INDEX IDX_FTTX_TM_NE_STATUS ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (NE_STATUS ASC)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 2
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 65536
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
CREATE INDEX IDX_MASTFTT_FSAID ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (FSAID ASC)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 2
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 65536
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
CREATE INDEX IDX_MASTFTT_STATUS ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (STATUS ASC)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 2
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 65536
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
CREATE INDEX INDX_ENT_TASK_TYPE ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (ENT_TASK_TYPE ASC)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 2
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 65536
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
CREATE INDEX INDX_SOLUTION_ID ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (SOLUTION_ID ASC)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 2
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 65536
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
CREATE INDEX INDX_TM_MDUID ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (MDUID ASC)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 2
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 65536
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
CREATE INDEX SDE.INDX_TM_WORKORDER ON APP_FTTX.FTTX_TASKMASTER (WORKORDER ASC)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE "SDE"
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 2
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 65536
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX R4914_SDE_ROWID_UK ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (OBJECTID ASC)
NOLOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 0
INITRANS 4
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 65536
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
CREATE INDEX REQUEST_ID ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (REQUEST_ID ASC)
NOLOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 0
INITRANS 4
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 81920
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
CREATE INDEX ROLE_INX ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (ROLE ASC)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 2
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 65536
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
CREATE INDEX SOURCE ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (SOURCE ASC)
NOLOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 0
INITRANS 4
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 81920
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)ALTER TABLE FTTX_TASKMASTER
ADD CONSTRAINT FTTX_TM_UQ_TASKID UNIQUE
(
  TASKID
)
ENABLE
-- Unable to render INDEX DDL for object APP_FTTX.CONSTRUCTOR_DATE_INDEX with DBMS_METADATA attempting internal generator.
CREATE INDEX CONSTRUCTOR_DATE_INDEX ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (CONSTRUCTORDATE ASC)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 2
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 65536
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
-- Unable to render INDEX DDL for object APP_FTTX.R4914_SDE_ROWID_UK with DBMS_METADATA attempting internal generator.
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX R4914_SDE_ROWID_UK ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (OBJECTID ASC)
NOLOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 0
INITRANS 4
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 65536
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
-- Unable to render INDEX DDL for object APP_FTTX.IDX_MAST_OF_CODE with DBMS_METADATA attempting internal generator.
CREATE INDEX IDX_MAST_OF_CODE ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (OFFER_CODE ASC)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 2
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 81920
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
-- Unable to render INDEX DDL for object APP_FTTX.IDX_MASTFTT_STATUS with DBMS_METADATA attempting internal generator.
CREATE INDEX IDX_MASTFTT_STATUS ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (STATUS ASC)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 2
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 65536
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
-- Unable to render INDEX DDL for object APP_FTTX.IDX_MASTFTT_TASKID with DBMS_METADATA attempting internal generator.
CREATE INDEX IDX_MASTFTT_TASKID ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (TASKID ASC)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 2
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 65536
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
-- Unable to render INDEX DDL for object APP_FTTX.IDX_MASTFTT_JC_SAPID with DBMS_METADATA attempting internal generator.
CREATE INDEX IDX_MASTFTT_JC_SAPID ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (JC_SAP_ID ASC)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 2
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 65536
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
-- Unable to render INDEX DDL for object APP_FTTX.IDX_MASTFTT_LAYER with DBMS_METADATA attempting internal generator.
CREATE INDEX IDX_MASTFTT_LAYER ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (LAYER ASC)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 2
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 65536
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
-- Unable to render INDEX DDL for object APP_FTTX.IDX_MASTFTT_FSAID with DBMS_METADATA attempting internal generator.
CREATE INDEX IDX_MASTFTT_FSAID ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (FSAID ASC)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 2
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 65536
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
-- Unable to render INDEX DDL for object APP_FTTX.IDX_TASKMASTER_JPID with DBMS_METADATA attempting internal generator.
CREATE INDEX IDX_TASKMASTER_JPID ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (JIOPOINT_SAPID ASC)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 2
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 65536
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
-- Unable to render INDEX DDL for object APP_FTTX.IDX_TASKMASTER_ASSIGNTO with DBMS_METADATA attempting internal generator.
CREATE INDEX IDX_TASKMASTER_ASSIGNTO ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (ASSIGNEDTO ASC)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 2
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 65536
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
-- Unable to render INDEX DDL for object APP_FTTX.IDX_DEVIATION_ACTION with DBMS_METADATA attempting internal generator.
CREATE INDEX IDX_DEVIATION_ACTION ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (DEVIATION_ACTION ASC)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 2
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 65536
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
-- Unable to render INDEX DDL for object APP_FTTX.INDX_TM_MDUID with DBMS_METADATA attempting internal generator.
CREATE INDEX INDX_TM_MDUID ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (MDUID ASC)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 2
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 65536
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
-- Unable to render INDEX DDL for object APP_FTTX.ROLE_INX with DBMS_METADATA attempting internal generator.
CREATE INDEX ROLE_INX ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (ROLE ASC)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 2
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 65536
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
-- Unable to render INDEX DDL for object APP_FTTX.IDX_OFFER_CODE_ROLE with DBMS_METADATA attempting internal generator.
CREATE INDEX IDX_OFFER_CODE_ROLE ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (OFFER_CODE ASC, ROLE ASC)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 2
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 65536
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
-- Unable to render INDEX DDL for object APP_FTTX.SOURCE with DBMS_METADATA attempting internal generator.
CREATE INDEX SOURCE ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (SOURCE ASC)
NOLOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 0
INITRANS 4
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 81920
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
-- Unable to render INDEX DDL for object APP_FTTX.REQUEST_ID with DBMS_METADATA attempting internal generator.
CREATE INDEX REQUEST_ID ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (REQUEST_ID ASC)
NOLOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 0
INITRANS 4
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 81920
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
-- Unable to render INDEX DDL for object APP_FTTX.FTTX_TASKMASTER_DSAIDINX with DBMS_METADATA attempting internal generator.
CREATE INDEX FTTX_TASKMASTER_DSAIDINX ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (DSAID ASC)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 2
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 65536
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
-- Unable to render INDEX DDL for object APP_FTTX.INDX_SOLUTION_ID with DBMS_METADATA attempting internal generator.
CREATE INDEX INDX_SOLUTION_ID ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (SOLUTION_ID ASC)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 2
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 65536
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
-- Unable to render INDEX DDL for object APP_FTTX.INDX_ENT_TASK_TYPE with DBMS_METADATA attempting internal generator.
CREATE INDEX INDX_ENT_TASK_TYPE ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (ENT_TASK_TYPE ASC)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 2
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 65536
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
-- Unable to render INDEX DDL for object APP_FTTX.IDX_COMP_TSK with DBMS_METADATA attempting internal generator.
CREATE INDEX IDX_COMP_TSK ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (STATUS ASC, LAYER ASC, NE_STATUS ASC)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 2
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 65536
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)
-- Unable to render INDEX DDL for object APP_FTTX.IDX_FTTX_TM_NE_STATUS with DBMS_METADATA attempting internal generator.
CREATE INDEX IDX_FTTX_TM_NE_STATUS ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (NE_STATUS ASC)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE "APP_FTTX"
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 2
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL 65536
  NEXT 1048576
  MINEXTENTS 1
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
)



-- Unable to render TRIGGER DDL for object APP_FTTX.INCR_FTTX_TASKMASTER_OBJID with DBMS_METADATA attempting internal generator.
CREATE TRIGGER INCR_FTTX_TASKMASTER_OBJID BEFORE INSERT ON "APP_FTTX"."FTTX_TASKMASTER"
for each row
BEGIN
  if inserting then
      if :NEW."OBJECTID" is null then
         select INCR_TASKMASTER_OBJECTID.nextval into :NEW."OBJECTID" from dual;
      end if;
   end if;
END;
-- Unable to render TRIGGER DDL for object APP_FTTX.TRIG_FTTX_TASKMASTERHISTORY with DBMS_METADATA attempting internal generator.
CREATE TRIGGER "TRIG_FTTX_TASKMASTERHISTORY" BEFORE UPDATE OF STATUS,DEVIATION_ACTION ON FTTX_TASKMASTER
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.STATUS IS NOT NULL THEN
        IF UPPER(:NEW.STATUS) <> 'ASSIGNED' THEN

          INSERT INTO FTTX_TASKMASTER_HIST (
          IID,
          TASKID,
          STATUS,
          ROLE,
          ROLEUSER,
          REMARKS,
          STATUSDATE,
          CREATEDDATE,
          CONTRACTORID,
          WORKORDER,
          NE_STATUS,
          OFFER_CODE,
          APPVERSION,
          CONSTRUCTORDATE,
          DEVIATION_ACTION
          )
          VALUES(
          ID_TASKMASTERHISTORY.NEXTVAL,
          :OLD.TASKID,
          :OLD.STATUS,
          :OLD.ROLE,
          :OLD.ROLEUSER,
          :OLD.REMARKS,
          CASE WHEN :OLD.ROLE IN ('Field Engineer','Quality Engineer','Infra Lead') THEN :OLD.LAST_EDITED_DATE + 5.5/24 ELSE :OLD.MODIFIEDDATE END,
          SYSDATE,
          :OLD.CONTRACTORID,
          :OLD.WORKORDER,
          :OLD.NE_STATUS,
          :OLD.OFFER_CODE,
          :OLD.APPVERSION,
          :OLD.CONSTRUCTORDATE,
          :OLD.DEVIATION_ACTION
          );

        END IF;      

        IF UPPER(:NEW.STATUS) = 'COMPLETED' AND :NEW.OFFER_CODE IS NULL AND :NEW.CONSTRUCTORDATE IS NULL THEN
            :NEW.CONSTRUCTORDATE := SYSDATE;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Don't use `DISTINCT` and `ROWNUM=1` in the same query.

Comment: If you want help with the performance of queries then [edit] your question and include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX` statements for your tables; and the `EXPLAIN PLAN` for your query.

Comment: **Always** specify table aliases for referenced columns because `... AND fsaid NOT IN (
SELECT fsaid ...` may cause invalid column resolution and result in constant false.

Comment: @astentx That is good general advice. In this particular case an alias will not affect the result as the `NOT IN` sub-query is using the same table as the outer-query so if the column does not exist in the sub-query then it also will not exist in the outer-query and the query will fail with an error (however, it would still be good to get into the habit of using best practice even when you could technically get away without it).

Comment: @MT0: updated the question with table structure and its relevant information

Comment: Have you tried to use composite indexes on the columns you are querying? I.e. `fsaid, constructordate` and/or `jc_sap_id, status, fsiad, constructordate`

Comment: @MT0: No, I haven't tried that, can u help on 1-2 columns on how to create and implement it ?

Comment: Adapt your existing code `CREATE INDEX IDX_OFFER_CODE_ROLE ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (OFFER_CODE ASC, ROLE ASC)` and put a different constraint name and different columns in.

Answer (score 0):

While nobody can provide a fully vetted answer to any performance question without seeing your wait profile and having some knowledge of your data, in addition to seeing the execution plan (none of which was provided), it is often possible to make some off-the-cuff guesses based on the SQL alone.

Assuming these are all large tables and you're not using an Exadata, you most likely need three indexes:

```
 1. ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (CONSTRUCTORDATE)
 2. ON FTTX_TASKMASTER (FSAID,CONSTRUCTORDATE)
 3. ON JIOCENTERBOUNDARY(SAP_ID,R4GSTATENAME)
```

Explanation in place in the SQL (had to use a pic to show comments in color):

[image]

If you *are* using an Exadata you can dispense with at least the first index (on constructordate).

Lastly, assuming a very large data volume, this kind of report-style query usually benefits from parallelism, so you may need to hint it:

```
SELECT /*+ parallel(8) */ . . .
```

Also, remove the `DISTINCT` keyword from your inline select. The `ROWNUM=1` makes that an unnecessary operation, and you shouldn't be using it in an inline select anyway since it implies potentially multiple rows and only one row is permitted.

Your DDL shows a lot of single-column indexes, some of which are probably unnecessary. Don't index a column unless you know or suspect it will be needed as a selective predicate (a common or important query will apply a predicate against that column that will *greatly* reduce the # of rows - a modest reduction isn't enough to warrant indexing). Too many indexes and you just waste space and slow down inserts without getting any query benefit.